# Dynamically Created Grammar in NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I am working on a project using NLTK, and am having an issue with grammar generation. I've looked through a few other questions that exist on here, but I didn't see any that line up with mine.

I have explored using NLTK's `CFG` and `PCFG.fromString(str)` with a __ or a `ViterbiParser` respectively, but I want to be able to send a function a raw string and return its tokens. I have also tried using `nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(str))` in hopes that I can manually generate grammar trees from training data, which gets me close but fails given the string `My dog also likes eating sausage.`:

```
>>> nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize("My dog also likes eating sausage."))
[('My', 'PRP$'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('also', 'RB'), ('likes', 'VBZ'), 
('eating', 'JJ'), ('sausage', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

The word `eating` is tagged as an adjective, not a verb `VBG`.

Does there exist a grammar string/object/module which I can use without having to hard-code a grammar string NLTK? If not, is there a way in NLTK to generate a trained grammar without doing so manually? I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: The sentence you are trying to parse is the sample sentence in the [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) of the Stanford Parser, which does correctly PoS tags `eating`. Also, in the [online demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/tag/) of NLTK, the sentence is correctly tagged as well. The default tagger used in the NLTK demo is the one trained on the Penn Treebank, whereas all other taggers were trained on the NLTK corpora. It seems the taggers trained on the Penn treebank, Brown corpus and CoNLL2000 all successfully tag the sentence, so try changing your tagger to one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a potential solution to the problem, following a rabbit hole I found after researching what [SND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153801/snd)'s comment suggested. I was not aware of taggers other than the default one. What I ended up doing was training the default tagger with a built-in corpus (I will try different corpora later) using a series of taggers with backoff to the previous one. This is wrapped into a class for portability later, and is saved using `pickle`:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import *
from pickle import dump, load

CUTOFF = 2


class MyTagger:

    def __init__(self, path: str=None):
        self.isTrained = False
        self.path = path
        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, 'rb') as src:
                    self.tagger = load(src)
            except Exception:  # Broad Exception intentional; code not complete
                print("Pickle dump could not be loaded at path: ", path)
                pass

    def train(self, corpus) -> float:
        sents = corpus.tagged_sents(corpus.fileids())
        training_data = sents[int(len(sents) * 0.9):]
        testing_data = sents[:int(len(sents) * 0.1)]
        t0 = nltk.DefaultTagger('NN')
        t1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(training_data, cutoff=CUTOFF, backoff=t0)
        t2 = nltk.BigramTagger(training_data, cutoff=CUTOFF, backoff=t1)
        t3 = nltk.TrigramTagger(training_data, cutoff=CUTOFF, backoff=t2)
        self.tagger = t3
        if self.path:
            self.save(self.path)
        return self.evaluate(testing_data)

    def evaluate(self, corpus: list) -> float:
        return self.tagger.evaluate(corpus)

    def tag(self, text) -> list:
        if not self.tagger:
            raise Exception("")
        else:
            if isinstance(text, str):
                return self.tagger.tag(text.split())
            elif isinstance(text, list) and isinstance(text[0], str):
                return self.tagger.tag(text)

    def save(self, path):
        with open(path, 'wb') as out:
            dump(self.tagger, out, -1)
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
i = input("What to tag?  ")
tagger = MyTagger("brown_2.pickle")
try:
    print("Accuracy:", tagger.train(brown))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
print(tagger.tag(i))
```